# ASP.net, adding objects to a session variable

Tags: c#, asp.net, session

I'm trying to add an object(s) to a session variable across postbacks.  My code looks similar to the following.

```
  Supply sup =  Supplies.GetSupply(supplyItemID);

  Session["CartObjects"] += sup;
```

Now, the compiler throws an error saying that the "+=" operator cannot be used on type 'object' and 'Supply'.  Do I need to implement an interface on my Supply object that allows it to be added?  Is this possible or am I thinking about this in the completely wrong way.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try this:

```
Supply sup =  Supplies.GetSupply(supplyItemID); 
var cartObjects =  (Session["CartObjects"] as List<Supply>) ?? new List<Supply>();
cartObjects.Add(sup);
Session["CartObjects"] = cartObjects;
```

Answer (score 7):

unless you are trying to create some sort of array the syntax is just

```
Session["CartObjects"] = sup;
```

Comment: Yes, actually a list/array of objects.  Something along the lines of  ((List<Supply>)Session["CartObjects"]).Add(sup);

Answer (score 2):

No You dont need ,just Create a List of Supply  and Save it in session

```
var supplyList = new List<Supply >();
Supply sup =  Supplies.GetSupply(supplyItemID);
supplyList.Add(sup);
Session["CartObjects"] =supplyList;

and 
and cast it as supply List
var list = Session["CartObjects"] as List<Supply >
```